# Where to specify input @ in SAS?

Tags: sas

In the following code

```
data temp2;
input id 1 @3 date mmddyy11.;
cards;
1 11/12/1980
2 10/20/1996
3 12/21/1999
;
run;
```

what do `1 @3` symbols mean ? i presume `1` means that `id` is the first character in the data . I know that `@3` means that `date` variable starts with the third character , but why is it in front of `date` whereas `1` is after `id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's a badly written input statement.  You can specify input in a number of ways, and that mixes a few different ways to do things which happen to be allowed to mix (mostly).  Read the [SAS documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/63323/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0oaql83drile0n141pdacojq97s.htm) on input for more information.

Some common styles that you can use:

```
input @1 id $5.;  *Formatted input.  Allows specification of start position and informat, more useful if using date or other informat that is not just normal character/number.;
input id str $ otherstr $ date :date9.; *List input. This is for delimited text (like a CSV), still lets you specify informat.
input @'ID:' id $5.; *A special case of formatted input.  allows you to parse files that include the variable name, useful for old style files and some xml/json/etc. type files;
input x 1-10 y 11-20; *Column input. Not used very commonly as it's less flexible than start/informat style.;
```

There are other options (such as named input) that are not very frequently used in my experience.

In your specific example, the first variable is read in with column input [`id 1` says 'read a 1 character numeric from position 1 into id'] and then the second variable is read with formatted input [`@3 date mmddyy11.` says 'Read an 11 character date variable from position 3[-13] into a numeric using the date informat to translate it to a number.']  It also says someone gave you that code who isn't very familiar with SAS, since `mmddyy10.` is the correct informat - the 11th character cannot be helpful.

Comment: Thank you !!! I am surprised that this code has this many issues because I took it from a very good source http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/faq/increment_dates.htm

Comment: Indeed.  People learn bad habits I suppose :)  There's nothing inherently wrong with mixing the input, but it can be confusing, so it should really be avoided if it's not needed for some practical reason.